# Protractor UI Tests fail with Jenkins, successful on WinServer on cmd run

Tags: jenkins, protractor

I have a Jenkins configured on Windows Server for Nightly builds, compilations etc.. and UI Test (E2E Tests) automation which I'am having some problems.
We have a Web application runs on Chrome and need Jenkins to run these tests using protractor (with Selenium).

With the manual run from Windows cmd console, the tests finish successfully.

-------Here is the console output;

```
***C:\Jenkins\jobs\UI Automation\workspace> protractor e2e-tests/protractor.conf.js

Using ChromeDriver directly...

[launcher] Running 1 instances of WebDriver

WARNING - more than one element found for locator by.repeater("attachment in pos
t_item.attachments") - the first result will be used

.
Finished in 68.394 seconds

1 test, 8 assertions, 0 failures

[launcher] 0 instance(s) of WebDriver still running

[launcher] chrome #1 passed***
```

-----Here is the output of the run from Jenkins;

```
C:\Jenkins\jobs\UI Automation\workspace>protractor e2e-tests/protractor.conf.js  
Using ChromeDriver directly...
[launcher] Running 1 instances of WebDriver
WARNING - more than one element found for locator by.repeater("attachment in post_item.attachments") - the first result will be used
[31mF[0m
Failures:
  1) new_message_with_attachment should send new message with attachment
   Message:
     [31mElementNotVisibleError: element not visible
  (Session info: chrome=47.0.2526.111)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.13.307647 (5a7d0541ebc58e69994a6fb2ed930f45261f3c29),platform=Windows NT 6.0 SP2 x86_64)[0m
   Stacktrace:
     ElementNotVisibleError: element not visible
  (Session info: chrome=47.0.2526.111)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.13.307647 (5a7d0541ebc58e69994a6fb2ed930f45261f3c29),platform=Windows NT 6.0 SP2 x86_64)
    at new bot.Error (C:\Users\X\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\atoms\error.js:113:18)
    at Object.bot.response.checkResponse (C:\Users\x\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\atoms\response.js:106:9)
    at C:\Users\X\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver\webdriver.js:362:20
    at C:\Users\X\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\goog\base.js:1582:15
    at [object Object].webdriver.promise.ControlFlow.runInNewFrame_ (C:\Users\X\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver\promise.js:1654:20)
    at notify (C:\Users\X\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver\promise.js:465:12)
    at notifyAll (C:\Users\X\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver\promise.js:442:7)
    at resolve (C:\Users\X\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver\promise.js:420:7)
    at [object Object].fulfill (C:\Users\X\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver\promise.js:535:5)
    at C:\Users\X\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver\promise.js:1520:10
==== async task ====
WebElement.click()
    at [object Object].webdriver.WebDriver.schedule (C:\Users\X\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver\webdriver.js:345:15)
    at [object Object].webdriver.WebElement.schedule_ (C:\Users\X\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver\webdriver.js:1727:23)
    at [object Object].webdriver.WebElement.click (C:\Users\X\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver\webdriver.js:1832:15)
    at actionFn (C:\Users\X\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\lib\element.js:75:32)
    at C:\Users\X\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\lib\element.js:393:17
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at actionResults.getWebElements.then.then.e.stack (C:\Users\X\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\lib\element.js:392:9)
    at C:\Users\X\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\goog\base.js:1582:15
    at [object Object].webdriver.promise.ControlFlow.runInNewFrame_ (C:\Users\X\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver\promise.js:1654:20)
==== async task ====
Asynchronous test function: it()
    at [object Object].<anonymous> (C:\Users\X\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\jasminewd\index.js:93:33)
    at [object Object].<anonymous> (C:\Users\X\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\minijasminenode\lib\async-callback.js:45:37)
    at [object Object].jasmine.Block.execute (C:\Users\X\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\minijasminenode\lib\jasmine-1.3.1.js:1174:17)
    at [object Object].jasmine.Queue.next_ (C:\Users\X\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\minijasminenode\lib\jasmine-1.3.1.js:2209:31)
    at [object Object]._onTimeout (C:\Users\X\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\minijasminenode\lib\jasmine-1.3.1.js:2199:18)
Error
    at [object Object].ElementArrayFinder.applyAction_ (C:\Users\X\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\lib\element.js:389:21)
    at [object Object].self.(anonymous function) [as click] (C:\Users\X\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\lib\element.js:77:19)
    at [object Object].self.(anonymous function) [as click] (C:\Users\X\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\lib\element.js:697:11)
    at [object Object].<anonymous> (C:\Jenkins\jobs\UI Automation\workspace\e2e-tests\new_message_with_attachment.js:223:62)
    at C:\Users\X\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\jasminewd\index.js:94:14
    at [object Object].webdriver.promise.ControlFlow.runInNewFrame_ (C:\Users\X\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver\promise.js:1654:20)
    at [object Object].webdriver.promise.ControlFlow.runEventLoop_ (C:\Users\X\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver\promise.js:1518:8)
Error
    at [object Object].<anonymous> (C:\Jenkins\jobs\UI Automation\workspace\e2e-tests\new_message_with_attachment.js:76:3)
    at [object Object].jasmine.Env.describe_ (C:\Users\X\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\minijasminenode\lib\jasmine-1.3.1.js:913:21)
    at [object Object].jasmine.Env.describe (C:\Users\X\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\minijasminenode\lib\jasmine-1.3.1.js:898:15)
    at describe (C:\Users\X\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\minijasminenode\lib\jasmine-1.3.1.js:658:27)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Jenkins\jobs\UI Automation\workspace\e2e-tests\new_message_with_attachment.js:75:1)
Finished in 59.756 seconds
[31m1 test, 8 assertions, 2 failures
[0m
[launcher] 0 instance(s) of WebDriver still running
Build step 'Execute Windows batch command' marked build as failure
Discard old builds...
Sending e-mails to: me@home.com
Finished: FAILURE*
```

-------Here is the protractor.conf.js;

```
*exports.config = {
  allScriptsTimeout: 20000,
  specs: [
    'new_message_with_attachment.js',
  ],

  capabilities: {
    'browserName': 'chrome',
    'chromeOptions': {
    prefs: {'profile.managed_default_content_settings.notifications': 1}},
  shardTestFiles: true,
    maxSessions: 1

  },

  directConnect: true,
  jasmineNodeOpts: {
    defaultTimeoutInterval: 1000000
  }
};*
```

Any comments?

Comment: Does your Jenkins have some kind of display output, or are you using xvfb for a virtual display?

Comment: I could not find any display output, it would work in order to track which element could not be found. Additionally, the errors in the log changes from time to time, for instance I get some errors like "unknown error: Element is not clickable at point" or "No element found using locator: By.cssSelector("[class=\"btn btn-info btn-newpost\"]")" or "Index out of bound. Trying to access element at index:0, but there are only 0 elements". I think there are some problems on the background where the protractor is running, maybe on selenium side..

Comment: @eozen I've integrated protractor with Jenkins once. Didn't remember all the detail of failures but it is very unstable. I will suggest you to tried to use **xvfb**. And if Jenkins being a virtual machine, then machine's resouce can make a huge impact too. Make sure it has 2-4GB RAM and at least 2-4 processor each should have 2.0Ghz at least, also graphic VRAM should be at least 128MB (usable VRAM not config VRAM).

Comment: @LinhPham Thanks for the feedback. As you said it is unstable right now, I am getting different errors on every run. I am using Windows Server, so I cannot use xvfb, or? I think the Windows server configuration is ok, I have 8GB ram 2.4Ghz processor, that should be enough. But the tests are running very fast, and some errors like "element not found" are most probably because of the uncompleted webpage install..Sometimes it can even enter the login username with some missing characters.

Comment: @eozen, Got some useful info in your latest comment, I will give a try to make an answer in shortly :) ---- P.S. By the way, how many processors your got there? only one?

Comment: @LinhPham thanks :) it is Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU, it has 4 processors.

Answer (score 0):

It has been happened once for me when integrate Protractor with Jenkins CI. So according to your question, I will make some suggestions that will help to increase the stability of your e2e test.

As it seem like you are not just having a single problems here. And I am sure this will solve some of your problems but may not solve all of it.

---

> and some errors like "element not found" are most probably because of the uncompleted webpage install..
>
> ...I am getting different errors on every run

This is the most common issue with protractor, there are many cause for this to happen. But fortunately it can be avoid with very simple method combine with [**Page Object**](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/page-objects.md).

This is page object:

```js
var MyPage = function () {

    // SET ng-view or ui-view
    this.view = $('.view');

    // SET interactable components
    this.button = element(by.css('button'));

};

MyPage.prototype.get = function () {
    browser.setLocation('myRoute/something');
};

MyPage.prototype.waitForPresent = function() {
    var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
    browser.wait(EC.presenceOf(this.button), 10000);
};
```

In your test suite/spec:

```js
it("should test something", function() {
    var page = new MyPage();
    page.get();

    browser.waitForAngular();
    page.waitForPresent();

    page.button.click();
});
```

The trick here is using Expected conditions and wrote a prototype for your page object `waitForPresent` , waiting for the component(s) to be presented. Pick one that you think it will be the last one to got rendered on your view/page. 
(NOTE: you don't need to use page objects, but that will be quite a pain to manage when you suites getting bigger)

---

> But the tests are running very fast, and some errors like "element not found" are most probably because of the uncompleted webpage install..Sometimes it can even enter the login username with some missing characters.

It seem like you does have very good resources there (CPU and RAM), but the point you said that sometimes it missed some characters when logging in. This mean you are still lack of resource else where, and suspecting is your Graphic's resources. Graphic reources is lacking almost all of servers, because it don't always need to render something. And to deal with this, there is no code adjustment, trick or work-around to use. You must at least try either of these (or do both):

- Find away to run headless test. Because render browser is quite heavy. (use Chrome or FireFox, because PhantomJS is not recommended for protractor)
- Try to increase your graphic resource.

**EDIT** : there is an issue on github [Calling element.sendKeys() seems to not send all the keys](https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/698) it was first suspecting on an old version of Webdriver. But recently people who used latest version of Webdriver got it too. Unknow cause, but I am highly doubt it was due to lacking of some sort of resources. Anyways this is just for your informations. Hope it is helped :)

Comment: Thanks a lot for these suggestions, we will try to apply these (may not be in a short period of time) and sure will be letting you know about the result.