# Protractor test fails when launch directly on Windows Server 2012

Tags: protractor, windows-server-2012

I use Protractor 3.0.0 to measure UI performances of a web app.

I need to launch my test suites on a virtual machine running on Windows Server 2012. They run perfectly on my personal computer, but on the VM the tests go crazy:

1. My tests don't always properly click on dropdown menus (e.g. my debug messages indicate that the click on the logout link in a dropdown menu was successful but nothing happens)
2. When filling text fields A and B with values "valueA" and "valueB" in a form, the tests sometimes sends "valueAvalueB" in the field B

I tried launching tests with PhantomJS, and I still have the same problem with dropdown menus (I didn't check the values of text fields yet). In addition, the performance measurements seem to be too optimistic.

Does anyone encountered the same problem? I couldn't find anything describing that kind of problem...

I launch my tests directly from the VM (not using remote WebDriver or something).

Comment: Sounds like a spec issue to me, I have an answer for a similar question. But the OP couldn't tried it out (probably he was on some experiment). You can check the answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35033911/protractor-ui-tests-fail-with-jenkins-successful-on-winserver-on-cmd-run/35055884#35055884
--------- Also there are some difference since you are not running it on Jenkins server. But that is not much matter, just read throw the answer and try it if you can (It worked for me)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Indeed, this is not the same context but you describe some similar effects... I will discuss it with my manager. Thank you again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok [Link Pham](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1729688/linh-pham) this is what I feared... Headless browsers could fix the issues, but we want to measure times spent displaying items and refreshing them. Headless browsers could give too optimistic results (as I observed with PhantomJS when I gave it a try). I will try with headless Chrome.
I guess I will have a bunch of other questions, but your answer properly covers the scope of this specific question so I will close it. Thank you again .